# How to get pair device dialog to show when adb debugging over wireless

Tags: android

I'm trying to adb debug over wireless per [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb).  However, I'm only able to get to step 3/4: "Enable the Wireless debugging option"
and not able to find the pictured dialog for step 5 where it asks: "Select Pair device with pairing code. Take note of the pairing code, IP address, and port number displayed on the device (see image)."  I was wondering how to get this dialog to show up. This is on a Pixel 3 running Android 11. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Dont have a pixel 3, but below steps worked on Android 11 device:
Enable developer options and

```
   1. Open Developer Options
   2. Turn on Wireless Debugging and click it 
   3. Click on "Pair device with pairing code"
```

Comment: thanks! I should have mentioned that I was able to get to step 3 on the link: "Enable the Wireless debugging option." I'll include that in the OP now